# Check if dictionary contains value in Swift

Tags: swift, nsdictionary, nspredicate

Just simple task. I've got a dictionary `var types = [Int : String]()` which inits like an empty and after some user actions it fills with data. According to emptiness or some specific data in this dictionary I enable/disable a button in UI. 
Check for emptiness is easy, but how to check if dictionary contains certain value? 
Compiler suggested me a placeholder with predicate:

```
types.contains(predicate: ((Int, String)) throws -> Bool>)
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since you only want to check for existance of a given *value*, you can apply the `contains` method for the `values` properties of your dictionary (given native Swift dictionary), e.g.

```
var types: [Int : String] = [1: "foo", 2: "bar"]
print(types.values.contains("foo")) // true
```

As mentioned in [@njuri: answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38451375/4573247), making use of the `values` property of the dictionary can seemingly yield an overhead (I have not verified this myself) w.r.t. just checking the `contains` predicate directly against the value entry in the key-value tuple of each `Dictionary` element. Since Swift is fast, this shouldn't be an issue, however, unless you're working with a huge dictionary. Anyway, if you'd like to avoid using the `values` property, you could have a look at the alternatives given in the forementioned answer, or, use another alternative (`Dictionary` extension) as follows:

```
extension Dictionary where Value: Equatable {
  func containsValue(value : Value) -> Bool {
    return self.contains { $0.1 == value }
  }
}

types.containsValue("foo") // true
types.containsValue("baz") // false
```

Comment: @Brian Sorry, I don't follow.

Comment: swift 3 requires the extra value; types.containsValue(value: "foo")

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a function which is using `contains` method on dictionary.

Your specific case:

```
let dic : [Int : String] = [1 : "a", 2 : "b"]

func dictionary(dict : [Int : String], containsValue value : String)->Bool{

  let contains = dict.contains { (_,v) -> Bool in
      return v == value
  }
  return contains
}

let c = dictionary(dic, containsValue: "c") // false
let a = dictionary(dic, containsValue: "a") // true
```

Generic:

```
extension Dictionary{
  func containsValue<T : Equatable>(value : T)->Bool{
    let contains = self.contains { (k, v) -> Bool in

      if let v = v as? T where v == value{
        return true
      }
      return false
    }
    return contains
  }
}
```

I've tested this function against `dictionary.values.contains()` and it is roughly two times faster.

Comment: A statement `if condition { return true } else { return false }` can always be simplified to `return condition`.

Comment: Even a `Dictionary` extension could be better. The redundancy of `dictionary` is horrible and useless. Isn't better to call `yourDicrtionaryInstance.contains(_:)`?

Comment: W.r.t. to the last benchmarking paragraph: is this tested in an actual project or in a playground? I'm curious to see whether it'd be any difference in performance between the methods in an actual project, where you allow to compiler to be clever (make sure to never perform benchmarks in a playground).

Comment: @LucaD'Alberti I've added a generic extension to `Dictionary` what do you think about it?

Comment: @dfri I've tested using Xcode Performance testing that means code was compiled, run 10 times and measured average execution time.

Comment: @njuri ok, thanks. Note that a generic for a search task as this needn't be as verbose; allowing searching of types in a dict that differ to the `Value` type. I included a generic alternative to my answer that only allows searching for instances of types that equals the value type (given that this type i `Equatable`).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check if already contains a ***value*** this would be the way:

```
if !yourDictionary.values.contains("Zero") {
   yourDictionary[newItemKey] = newItemValue; //addNewItem
}
else {
    print("this value already exists");
}
```

And this one if you want to check if the ***key*** exists:

1. You get the item to add to your dictionary.
2. Check if the item's key already exists
3. If it doesn't, append the item or enable the button.

   ```
   //1
   let newItemKey = 0
   let newItemValue = "Zero"
   //2
   let keyExists = yourDictionary[newItemKey] != nil
   //3
   if !keyExists {
       yourDictionary[newItemKey] = newItemValue; //addNewItem
   }
   else {
   print("This key already exists");
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

The dictionary getter returns an [**optional**](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optional) value.

```swift
let dictionary = ["ben": "says hi"]
let containsAlpha = dictionary["alpha"] != nil
let containsBen = dictionary["ben"] != nil
```

[image]